# Hash Tables: Ransom Note Hackerrank (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, counter

Harold is a kidnapper who wrote a ransom note, but now he is worried it will be traced back to him through his handwriting. He found a magazine and wants to know if he can cut out whole words from it and use them to create an untraceable replica of his ransom note. The words in his note are case-sensitive and he must use only whole words available in the magazine. He cannot use substrings or concatenation to create the words he needs.

Given the words in the magazine and the words in the ransom note, print Yes if he can replicate his ransom note exactly using whole words from the magazine; otherwise, print No.

For example, the note is "Attack at dawn". The magazine contains only "attack at dawn". The magazine has all the right words, but there's a case mismatch. The answer is No.

I am failing 5 of the test cases and am having trouble as to why. Any help is welcome. Thanks!

[HackerRank Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps)

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
   c1 = Counter(magazine)
   c2 = Counter(note)

   if (c2.items() <= c1.items()):
      print('Yes')
   else:
      print('No')
```

Comment: something like this: https://medium.com/@wlucas0311/harmless-ransom-note-7d072e9efbd1

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just compare c1.items() with c2.items().  There is no guarantee of the order of the items.  Try a short example and print out c1.items() and c2.items().  That's not how tuple comparison works.

You can, instead do something like:

```
all(c1[key] >= c2[key] for key in c2.keys())
```

which checks each letter that occurs in c2, individually and makes sure that there are that many keys in the magazine.

You might also want to ignore spaces!  It would be amusing to claim you couldn't generate a ransom note because there weren't enough spaces in the magazine.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's said not to use exception as control structures but this is the most elegant exception... pun intended :)

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    for word in note:
        try:
            magazine.remove(word)
        except:
            print("No")
            return
    print("Yes")
```